# Running X86 binaries on armv7

Tags: arm, qemu, x86

I am trying to run a SNBC USB printer on Raspberry Pi2.

For that I need to copy the filter binary of the SNBC USB printer to `/usr/lib/cups/filter`. But the filter binary is compiled using a x86 processor (Manufacturer does not have interest to support arm) where as I use `armv7`. I know it will not work but for a curiosity I tried and cups says `/usr/lib/cups/filter/rasterorp3150 failed`.

I looked for solutions on the internet and people suggest to use Qemu. But it is for a complete x86 to arm platform. Is there a way to convert the x86 binary to arm binary in a easy uncomplicated way?

By the way, is converting the x86 binary using a `hexedit` tool to an equivalent `armv7` binary a good idea? (`opcode` conversion)

If so, can anyone give some idea on how to do it?

Comment: If you have the source you can "cross compile" for a different "target" arch.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/221549/is-it-possible-to-run-an-x86-binary-on-an-arm-processor

Answer (score 17):

You can't easily convert an *x86* binary to ARM. If you can't get the source code, or an ARM binary from the manufacturer, and you really do want to use the printer with your Pi2, then the Qemu approach is the correct one in this case, although it will likely be very slow. Qemu does full system emulation but it also works very well for single process emulation.

I'm assuming you have some sort of Debian derivative on your Pi2 (I'm not sure this will work with Raspbian though), and that the binary you have is for `i386` (if it's 64-bit, use `amd64` instead). Start by adding `i386` as a foreign architecture:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

Then run `ldd` on the binary and add any required libraries; typically

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386
```

and anything else with the `:i386` suffix added. Make sure this doesn't remove any installed package; hopefully everything you need is multiarch-enabled. (Otherwise the rest won't work.)

Once you've done that, install `qemu-user-static` if it isn't already installed (along with its `binfmt-support` recommendation); then you can use `qemu-i386-static` to run your program:

```
qemu-i386-static /usr/lib/cups/filter/rasterorp3150
```

In fact thanks to `binfmt-support` it should run directly (as pointed out by [Toby Speight](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/112566/toby-speight)):

```
/usr/lib/cups/filter/rasterorp3150
```

(`binfmt-support` will use Qemu to make this work transparently.)

If you don't want to use `binfmt-support`, move `rasterorp3150` away:

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/cups/filter/rasterorp3150 /usr/lib/cups/filter/rasterorp3150.x86
```

and install a script containing

```
#!/bin/sh
exec qemu-i386-static /usr/lib/cups/filter/rasterorp3150.x86 "$@"
```

as `/usr/lib/cups/filter/rasterorp3150`.

If you'd rather you can set up a chroot for all this; see `debootstrap` and its `--foreign` option (the chroot can be set up to use Qemu automatically).

Comment: In the being time this solution doesn't work, I always get error 404 while doing `apt update` after adding i386 arch.

Comment: @Mohammed what distribution are you using?

Comment: Raspbian, 11.2016 release. and I wanted to emulate i386

Comment: OK, so the error you're getting is normal, Raspbian doesn't provide `i386` binaries. This only works with architectures which are supported in the distro you're using.

Comment: I had to mention that I tried that with both Rasbian and Ubuntu. Any good disto suggesion where I can emulate i386 on armhf host?

Comment: @Mohammed I would have expected this to work with Ubuntu. I know it works with Debian (8 or 9), that's what I use on my ARM devices and it's what I tested with when writing this answer.

Comment: OK now by help of a friend, we managed to get it work, but now **the server crashes always in some time after running**, in `top` I can see it still running, but of course I cannot connect to it any more untill I `kill -9` the process and restart it. Any idea?d

Comment: @Mohammed Unfortunately not, I suggest you [ask a new question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).